# Bot framework javascript_nodejs v4: Unable to use Default Locale in DateTimePrompt (Dutch)

Tags: node.js, botframework

In a waterfall dialog step, I need a date from the user. The users language is Dutch. I have tried multiple options, but the locale keeps using 'en-en'. Dutch dates like '1 April' and '26 Juni' are not recognized.

My prompt:

```js
this.addDialog(new DateTimePrompt(WHEN_PROMPT, this.datePromptValidator, 'nl-nl'));
```

I use it like this

```js
const promptOptions = { retryPrompt: 'Hier kan ik geen datum uithalen.' };
return await stepContext.prompt(WHEN_PROMPT, promptOptions);
```

and the validator

```js
async datePromptValidator(promptContext) {
    return promptContext.recognized.succeeded;
}
```

Would appreciate some help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This of "defaultLocale" as more of a fall-back if there's no indication what the user's locale is *supposed* to be.

In the current code, [`activity.locale` is used first, if it exists](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/datetimePrompt.ts#L74):

```js
const locale: string =  activity.locale || this.defaultLocale || 'en-us';
```

This is [what's specified in the param info](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/datetimePrompt.ts#L51):

> - @param defaultLocale (Optional) locale to use if `TurnContext.activity.locale` is not specified. Defaults to a value of `en-us`.

This is the same for other prompts:

- [ChoicePrompt](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/choicePrompt.ts#L123)
- [ConfirmPrompt](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/confirmPrompt.ts#L135)

If you're running into this when testing, here's how to change locale in a few clients:

**Emulator**:

[image]

**WebChat**:

```js
window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
        {
          directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            token: 'YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_TOKEN'
          }),
          userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID',
          username: 'Web Chat User',
          locale: 'en-US', // CHANGE THIS HERE!!
          botAvatarInitials: 'WC',
          userAvatarInitials: 'WW'
        },
        document.getElementById('webchat')
      );
```

**Teams**:

Click your profile, then Settings, then:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Passing the local is not the problem I noticed. The recognizer package does not support Dutch for DateTime. At least for Javascript. For .net there is some support but disabled. Guess I need to find something else or build my own recognizer.

Comment: @Hessel Ah yeah, I see. Unfortunately, all of our packages rely on `recognizers-text` and we pin our culture support to theirs. And you're correct. Currently [they don't support Dutch](https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text/tree/master/JavaScript/packages/recognizers-date-time/src/resources). Your only/best option would be to write your own `DateTimePrompt`. You should also be able to do something with a custom validator, as well, since I believe the `promptContext` should contain the original activity and you could pull the `locale` from there.

Comment: Textprompt with PromptValidator, Regex and turnState did the trick